# Creating a Klauder Wavelet in Matlab to be used in making a synthetic trace

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I have some reflectivity data which I am going to convolute with a vibroseis (Klauder) wavelet to get a seismic trace. i am struggling to do the code. I need it to have a sweep from 2500Hz to 7000Hz with a duration of 0.03s (30ms). i have downloaded the CREWES toolbox with the different wavelet functions in but i dont know how to produce it. can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.
You may want to check pp.7 to 10 of [this ebook](https://assets.cambridge.org/97811071/70148/excerpt/9781107170148_excerpt.pdf).

There are two ways to do this. You may:

1. Create your klauder wavelet from scratch. This is the approach detailed [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/841505-hamming-window-for-a-wavelet).
2. Call the `klauder` function predefined in the CREWES package, as described in the ebook. In this case, you will directly specify the min and max frequencies used for your sweep as arguments in the function: `[wk,twk]=klauder(fmin,fmax,dt,slen,tlen,staper);`